# Getting Employee ID from Azure AD

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-active-directory

I am able to retrieve the **Job Title, Department**. I want to be able to retrieve the **Employee ID.** As shown in the second image, I need to know the parameters to get the Employee ID.

```
This is my HTML.
 <p>{{user.employee id}} </p>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space there. It should be user.employeeid as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization).

Comment: It is still not able to retrieve the id